# web.xml error when using 'HttpOnly' and 'Secure' attributes

Tags: jsf, web.xml, session-hijacking

I want to make my JSF application less vulnerable to session
hijacking. So I have added the following code to the web.xml file.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        60
    </session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <secure>true</secure>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <max-age>1800</max-age>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Then when I run the application, deployment fails in Payara Server with the following message.

```
Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [chims-0.1].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":http-only}'. One of '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":max-age}' is expected.
```

I use version 4 of web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http-only` element comes before `secure` element in the sequence. See [web-common_4_0.xsd](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-common_4_0.xsd) for the `cookie-configType` type description.

Your config should be:

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        60
    </session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
        <max-age>1800</max-age>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Comment: It works without any issue. Thank you